# when is the next maintenance due on patent #8,425,176

Tags: araf

I am the inventor of patent #8,425,176. I would like to know the date at which I will be required to pay another maintenance fee.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for specific legal advice which an online site like this cannot give.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this page:
https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees/fees/details?applicationNumber=12800886&patentNumber=8425176

The next maintenance fee payment window opens on 04/23/2020.